# SQL Query with multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been beating my head on the desk trying to figure this one out. I have a table that stores job information, and reasons for a job not being completed. The reasons are numeric,01,02,03,etc. You can have two reasons for a pending job. If you select two reasons, they are stored in the same column, separated by a comma. This is an example from the **JOBID** table:

```
Job_Number     User_Assigned     PendingInfo

1              user1             01,02
```

There is another table named **Pending**, that stores what those values actually represent. 01=Not enough info, 02=Not enough time, 03=Waiting Review.  Example:

```
Pending_Num    PendingWord

01             Not Enough Info
02             Not Enough Time
```

What I'm trying to do is query the database to give me all the job numbers, users, pendinginfo, and pending reason.  I can break out the first value, but can't figure out how to do the second. What my limited skills have so far:

```
select Job_number,user_assigned,SUBSTRING(pendinginfo,0,3),pendingword
from jobid,pending
where
    SUBSTRING(pendinginfo,0,3)=pending.pending_num and
    pendinginfo!='00,00' and
    pendinginfo!='NULL'
```

What I would like to see for this example would be:

```
Job_Number  User_Assigned   PendingInfo   PendingWord       PendingInfo  PendingWord

1           User1           01            Not Enough Info   02           Not Enough Time
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is changing the schema an option?  This relation should really be either a mapping table or a secondary reason column.

Comment: Database 101 - **first** normal form (1NF): each row/column cell must contain at most **one value**.

Answer (score 5):

You really *shouldn't* store multiple items in one column if your SQL is ever going to want to process them individually. The "SQL gymnastics" you have to perform in those cases are both ugly hacks and performance degraders.

The ideal solution is to split the individual items into separate columns and, for 3NF, move those columns to a separate table as rows if you *really* want to do it properly (but baby steps are probably okay if you're sure there will never be more than two reasons in the short-medium term).

Then your queries will be both simpler and faster.

---

However, if that's not an option, you can use the afore-mentioned SQL gymnastics to do something like:

```
where find ( ',' |fld| ',', ',02,' ) > 0
```

assuming your SQL dialect has a string search function (`find` in this case, but I think `charindex` for SQLServer).

This will ensure all sub-columns begin and start with a comma (comma plus field plus comma) and look for a specific desired value (with the commas on either side to ensure it's a full sub-column match).

---

If you *can't* control what the application puts in that column, I would opt for the DBA solution - DBA solutions are defined as those a DBA has to do to work around the inadequacies of their users :-).

Create two new columns in that table and make an insert/update trigger which will populate them with the two reasons that a user puts into the original column.

Then query those two *new* columns for specific values rather than trying to split apart the old column.

This means that the cost of splitting is only on row insert/update, not on _every single select`, amortising that cost efficiently.

---

Still, my answer is to re-do the schema. That will be the best way in the long term in terms of speed, readable queries and maintainability.

Comment: Yes, recreating would be the best way, but that is not an option at this point. This is the situation I have to work with.  Sorry, forgot to mention that this is MS SQL 2008

Comment: Then tell your bosses it's a bad idea then try the `charindex` option. And, if the performance sucks, you can then tell your bosses you were right and they were idiots, hopefully with more tact than I'm usually capable of :-)

Comment: I will give that charindex a try.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you are just maintaining the code and it's not a brand new implementation.
Please consider to use a different approach using a support table like this:

```
JOBS TABLE
jobID | userID
--------------
1     | user13
2     | user32
3     | user44
--------------

PENDING TABLE
pendingID | pendingText
---------------------------
01        | Not Enough Info
02        | Not Enough Time
---------------------------

JOB_PENDING TABLE
jobID | pendingID
-----------------
1     | 01
1     | 02
2     | 01
3     | 03
3     | 01
-----------------
```

You can easily query this tables using JOIN or subqueries.
If you need retro-compatibility on your software you can add a view to reach this goal.

Answer (score 3):

I have a tables like:

```
Events
---------
eventId int
eventTypeIds nvarchar(50)
...

EventTypes
--------------
eventTypeId
Description
...
```

Each Event can have multiple eventtypes specified.

All I do is write 2 procedures in my site code, not SQL code

1. One procedure converts the table field (eventTypeIds) value like "3,4,15,6" into a ViewState array, so I can use it any where in code.
2. This procedure does the opposite it collects any options your checked and converts it in

Answer (score 2):

If changing the schema *is* an option (which it probably should be) shouldn't you implement a many-to-many relationship here so that you have a bridging table between the two items? That way, you would store the number and its wording in one table, jobs in another, and "failure reasons for jobs" in the bridging table...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a similar question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704320/how-to-find-maximum-frequent-item-sets-from-large-transactional-data-file/2719551#2719551)

```
;WITH Numbers AS 
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS N
    FROM JobId
), 
Split AS 
( 
    SELECT JOB_NUMBER, USER_ASSIGNED, SUBSTRING(PENDING_INFO, Numbers.N, CHARINDEX(',', PENDING_INFO + ',', Numbers.N) - Numbers.N) AS PENDING_NUM
    FROM JobId
    JOIN Numbers ON Numbers.N <= DATALENGTH(PENDING_INFO) + 1 
    AND SUBSTRING(',' + PENDING_INFO, Numbers.N, 1) = ','
) 
SELECT *
FROM Split JOIN Pending ON Split.PENDING_NUM = Pending.PENDING_NUM
```

The basic idea is that you have to multiply each row as many times as there are `PENDING_NUM`s. Then, extract the appropriate part of the string

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with DBA perspective not to store multiple values in a single field it is doable, as bellow, practical for application logic and some performance issues. 
Let say you have 10000 user groups, each having average 1000 members. You may want to have a table user_groups with columns such as groupID and membersID. Your membersID column could be populated like this: 
(',10,2001,20003,333,4520,') each number being a memberID, all separated with a comma. Add also a comma at the start and end of the data. Then your select would use like '%,someID,%'.
If you can not change your data ('01,02,03') or similar, let say you want rows containing 01 you still can use " select ... LIKE '01,%' OR '%,01' OR '%,01,%' " which will insure it match if at start, end or inside, while avoiding similar number (ie:101).