# How to perform split operation on strings and attach to specific ids using SQL SERVER 2000(Without cursor)?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table wuth the folowing structure

```
PickupPointCode     LocationCode        ClientCode

    1           LOC1            Client1/Client2
    2           LOC2            Client3/Client4/Client5
    3           LOC3            Client6
```

The desired output being

```
PickupPointCode     LocationCode        ClientCode

1           LOC1            Client1
1           LOC1            Client2
2           LOC2            Client3
2           LOC2            Client4
2           LOC2            Client5
3           LOC3            Client6
```

Using SQL serevr 2005 I wrote the below query to get this done

```
;WITH cte AS (    
SELECT         
 PickupPointCode
 ,LocationCode
 ,CAST('<i>' + REPLACE(ClientCode, '/', '</i><i>') + '</i>' AS XML) AS ClientCodes   
FROM <TABLE NAME>)
SELECT     
 PickupPointCode
 ,LocationCode
 ,x.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS ClientCode
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY ClientCodes.nodes('//i') x(i)
```

But now I have to do the same thing using **SQL SERVER 2000**. How can I perform the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to multiply each row as many times as there are CLIENTs. Then, extract the appropriate part of the string.

Have a look at some example queries that work on SQL2005+ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800104/sql-query-with-multiple-values-in-one-column/2800393#2800393).
You will need to work with an extra table that contains sequential numbers in SQL2000.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
(
   N INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
GO

DECLARE @rows AS INT;
SET @rows = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers VALUES(1);
WHILE(@rows <= 1000)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers SELECT N + @rows FROM dbo.Numbers;
   SET @rows = @rows * 2;
END
```

This is the numbers table you can join onto. And below is the query that should work on SQL 2000.

```
SELECT PickupPointCode, LocationCode,
    SUBSTRING(ClientCode, Numbers.N,
        CHARINDEX('/', ClientCode + '/', Numbers.N) - Numbers.N) AS ClientCode 
    FROM <TABLE_NAME> 
    JOIN Numbers ON Numbers.N <= DATALENGTH(ClientCode) + 1  
    AND SUBSTRING('/' + ClientCode, Numbers.N, 1) = '/'
```